# Getting actual row number from Excel sheet using mganss/ExcelMapper

Tags: c#, excel

I am currently working on a project where I need to map `.xlsx` files into objects in C#.

I am using the mganss/ExcelMapper for this and it is actually working quite well.

I need the actual spreadsheet row number mapped in my C# object as well, but can't seem to figure out how to get it.

Is it possible to grab the spreadsheet row number using mganss/ExcelMapper? (The documentation doesn't seem to describe this)

I tried reading the documentation for mganss/ExcelMapper and also using the intelliSense provided by Visual Studio, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose a field to use a custom SetProperty method using [Custom Mapping](https://github.com/mganss/ExcelMapper#custom-mapping). You would need to ensure that this field will not be empty or else the method won't be invoked for that row object.

The **c** param contains all sorts of information of the cell including its RowIndex. The **o** param is the row object whose property to set. With these you can set any additional property of the object before returning the value of the field. Not the best way but I think it is the only way for now.

For example:

```
excel.AddMapping<Employee>("Employee ID", p => p.EmployeeID)
    .SetPropertyUsing<Employee>((o, v, c) =>
    {
        o.RowNumber = c.RowIndex;
        return v;
    });

class Employee
{
    [Column("Employee ID")]
    public string EmployeeID {get; set;}
    [Ignore]
    public int RowNumber {get; set;}
}
```